# How to pass variables to a CFC on Form submission without using hidden fields?

Tags: coldfusion

*Using: ColdFusion 10, JQuery 1.9, IIS*

I made a CFC (allows remote access) which handles the insertion of comments into a database, whether they are new comments or replies to an existing one.

I have a Form which submits to this CFC when you want to make a comment.

At the moment I am passing (as hidden fields) form variables to the CFC to tell it various things about the comment that's to be inserted: e.g. which `User` the comment is for (the RecipientID) and which `CommentID` its in reference to (if its a reply). These values change a lot because sometimes a user is replying to another user's comment.

I don't want to send the hidden variables in my form because it can easily be modified by a malicious person. How can I send the main Form information using form variables (e.g. the comment body) but pass the sensitive variables using just ColdFusion so its not manipulable by a hacker?

One thing I could do is submit back to the page itself and then use `<cfinvoke>` to call the CFC and pass in the arguments. I would set the arguments in the invocation rather than in the Form. Would this be the correct way to do it?

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: I'm using JQuery AJAX to submit the form and also using it to get information about a comment if the user wants to reply to a comment. It basically grabs the CommentID and does an AJAX call to find out who made the comment in the first place. The reply is then sent to the correct person.

Comment: @volumeone I think what he meant is that this is ajax / web app related in general and not specific to jQuery enough to have this tagged with jQuery.

Comment: ok I've removed the JQuery tag

Comment: Am I missing something here or can cfqueryparam not handle this issue?

Comment: @mkross1983, you are missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding, "One thing I could do is submit back to the page itself and then use  to call the CFC and pass in the arguments. I would set the arguments in the invocation rather than in the Form. Would this be the correct way to do it?"

I think this would be a lot better than submitting to the cfc which is what you say you are doing now.  Slight variations of this theme are:

- Submit to another page which invokes the cfc method.
- Forget the cfc and put the database call into a .cfm page.  In
  fact, if the cfc contains nothing but the insert query and is not
  used elsewhere, it's unnecessary.

As far as not using hidden form fields goes, you might be in trouble.  The user info can be stored in the session scope as suggested by Henry, but the recipient info is harder to protect.  You could make the recipient id part of the form field name.  Then to protect yourself from neer do wells, add another check on the cgi.http_referrer variable.

Comment: I submit forms to the same page and then invoke a CFC with the form arguments.  How would including a .cfm page be any different then invoking a CFC, you would still be using the same form variables, would you not?

Comment: Both your comment and my answer suggest that the form be submitted to a .cfm page instead of a .cfc.  The difference is what page that is.  You are submitting to the page with the form code, and I suggested another page.  Within the context of the this question, I see that detail to be irrelevent.

Comment: Why is this better than submitting to a CFC? You can submit data to a CFC over AJAX just as easily as you can doing it the way you suggest. If user information is stored in session scope, that information can still be used if submitting data to a CFC directly.

Comment: Whether one option is better than another often depends on the situation at hand.  Even then, it is often a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 5):

The only place where the malicious users can't modify easily is in the `Session`.

Keep sensitive stuff in the `Session`, and make sure the logged in user has the proper right to do the action they requested (e.g. can delete their own stuff only, not other ppl's stuff)

Comment: Both this answer and mine have the same problem.  The sensitive information has to be persisted somehow.  You can't make it a session variable until you first collect it and you can't send it to a cfc until you first collect it.  This is not so much a problem with the user information as it is with the recipient information.

Comment: How about using the Request scope rather than Session scope?

Comment: Sure as long as you know its limitation.